# rxdatastep transforms as.date

Tags: sql-server, r, date

I have a column in a DS that contain date as 31/01/2017 and then when I run rxDataStep I get this warning:

*WARNING: Cannot directly import 'DATE' as 'Date' data.
Try as.Date() in a 'transform', for example for character data like "2011-10-01": 
as.Date(DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")*

then introduced transforms in the rxdatastep

*rxDataStep(inData = inTextData, outFile = itemsDS, transforms = list(DATE2 = as.Date(DATE, "%d-%m-%Y")), overwrite = TRUE)*

which returns NULL in DATA2 column
If I use "%d/%/%Y" column DATA has value 27/05/2014 and DATA2 16217

the question is how I manage that DATA2 after transformation has in it a date format?

C